# Unit test doesn't update value on styled input

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a React component

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input``;

export default function FormInput (props) {
  const { name, type, value, label, placeholder, onChange} = props;

  return (
      <Input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
  )
};
```

Using this unit test

```
test('it changes the value of the input', () => {
  let currentValue = 'Initial value';
  const setValue = (value) => {
    currentValue = value;
  }

  const component = <FormInput 
    name={'firstName'} 
    placeholder={'Enter your first name'} 
    value={currentValue} 
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />

  render(component);

  const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter your first name');

  fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'New value'}});

  expect(currentValue).toBe('New value');
  expect(input.value).toBe('New value');
});
```

The assertion on the value of the input is false, because it is still the initial value. This component works properly in the app. What am I setting up wrong in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit test was failing, because it wasn't being rerendered. I used the `rerender` function to render the component with the updated value. This is necessary because this test doesn't include the parent component holding state.

#### Updated test

```
test('it changes the value of the input', async () => {
  let currentValue = 'Initial value';
  const setValue = (value) => {
    currentValue = value;
  }

  const component = <FormInput 
    name={'firstName'} 
    placeholder={'Enter your first name'} 
    value={currentValue} 
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />

  const { rerender } = render(component);

  const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter your first name');

  fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'New value'}});

  rerender(<FormInput value={currentValue} />);

  expect(input.value).toBe('New value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it is easy to simulate text input by a user using the [`@testing-library/user-event`](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event) package.

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('it changes the value of the input', () => {
  let currentValue = 'Initial value';
  const setValue = (value) => {
    currentValue = value;
  }

  const component = <FormInput 
    name={'firstName'} 
    placeholder={'Enter your first name'} 
    value={currentValue} 
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />

  render(component);

  const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter your first name');

  userEvent.type(input, 'New value');

  expect(currentValue).toBe('New value');
  expect(input.value).toBe('New value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put setValue in your component body ? This logic clearly belongs to the component, you should have :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input``;

export default function FormInput (props) {
  const { name, type, label, placeholder} = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
      <input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
  )
};
```

Then in your test :

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

test('it changes the value of the input', () => {
    const component = <FormInput 
        name={'firstName'} 
        placeholder={'Enter your first name'} 
        value={currentValue} />

    render(component);

    const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter your first name');

    fireEvent.change(input, { target : { value : 'New value' } });
    expect(input).toHaveValue('New value');
});
```

Note that I use https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom to have more readable matchers.